# How can I pick just one value from random integer variable in java?

Tags: java

I would like a little help in java from you guys. My idea is to generate two integer variables from the random method and make it a constant string. Something like:

```
//In Class
Random rand = new Random();
protected int aux1 = rand.nextInt(9999), aux2 = rand.nextInt(10);
public final String x = aux1+"-"+aux2;  //is it possible to take just one time?

public String getX() {return x;}
```

But each time when I use the getX() in main class I got different values for x:  9626-3 4938-0 6500-6

instead of:  4938-0 4938-0 4938-0

How can I do this?

grateful for the attention.

Comment: Use `static` variables

Comment: Or create the object once and call get 3 times

Comment: You need to show us more code. Anything we say looking at this is mostly guesswork.

Comment: Q: have you resolved the problem?  Q: Do you understand what I was trying to convey in my response(s)?  SUGGESTION: if not, then let's "start from scratch".  Please update your post, and explain (again) exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Not "how", but "what". What are the inputs? What are the expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You got three different values ... because you *ASKED* for three different values.

It sounds like:

1. You want a string, consisting of two random integers and a dash.
2. The first integer is initialized once, the second always changes.
3. Potential solution:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
     protected Random rand = new Random();
     protected int aux1 = rand.nextInt(9999)

     public String makeIdentifier() {
       int aux2 = rand.nextInt(10);
       return aux1 + "-" + aux2;
     }
     ...
   ```

In other words, you've:

- refactored the "common code" into class members
- isolated the "unique" code in it's own method

---

**Update 1**

As I asked yesterday, it would be helpful if you'd better explain what you're trying to do.  *NOT* "how" you're trying to do it, but *WHAT* you're trying to accomplish.  By showing some output samples.

Let's go back to your initial post:

1. If you just want a string (e.g. "identifier") , with two random numbers separated by a dash...
2. ... and if you never want it to change over the lifetime of the object...
3. ... then here's how you could do it:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
     protected Random rand = new Random();
     protected String identifier = 
       rand.nextInt(9999) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10);

     public String getIdentifier() { return identifier; }
     }
     ...
   ```

Note that the member "identifier" is initialized *ONCE*, when the class is instantiated.

It sounds like that's what you were trying to do in your original post.  But - since you didn't show a complete [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), there's no way to tell exactly why it didn't work for you :(

---

**Update 2**

Thank you for your update. I can't overemphasize the value of a good [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

It's now clear that you have *TWO* classes. Each time you create a new instance of "Test2" ... you get a new value of "x".  That's the part you don't like.

SOLUTION:

- Don't call it "Test2".  Make your class do one thing, and do it well.  Let's say you want an "identifier string", like "XXXX-YY".  Then call your class "Identifier".  Or let's say you want "control information" like "identifier string" and "sequence number".  Then call it "ControlInformation".
- Let's say you want the *SAME* value, "XXXX-YY", no matter how many times you invoke the class, or how many instances you invoke it from.  Then, as Oleg aready suggested, use [static](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-static-members-of-a-Java-class)

EXAMPLE SOLUTION:

**ControlInformation.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * SAMPLE OUTPUT:
 *   Creating two object instances: c1 and c2...
 *   c1: 0, 1461-2
 *   c2: 0, 1461-2
 *   Incrementing c1..
 *   c1: 1, 1461-2
 *   c2: 0. 1461-2
 */
public class ControlInformation {

    // "identifier" initialized exactly once; will be the same for all instances
    protected static Random rand = new Random();
    protected static String identifier = 
      rand.nextInt(9999) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10);

    // "Sequence" will vary per object
    protected int sequence = 0;

    // Public access
    public String getIdentifier() { return identifier; }
    public int getSequence() { return sequence; }
    public int increment() { return ++sequence; }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Creating two object instances: c1 and c2...");
        ControlInformation c1 = new ControlInformation();
        ControlInformation c2 = new ControlInformation();
        System.out.println("c1: " + c1.getSequence() + ", " + c1.getIdentifier());
        System.out.println("c2: " + c2.getSequence() + ", " + c2.getIdentifier());

        System.out.println("Incrementing c1..");
        c1.increment();
        System.out.println("c1: " + c1.getSequence() + ", " + c1.getIdentifier());
        System.out.println("c2: " + c2.getSequence() + ". " + c2.getIdentifier());
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact, I want the both integer be initialized once; then, concatenate the two integers with dash in str x, keeping x fixed.

Comment: Please update your post showing the series of values you want.  For example, if the 1st call to getX() returns `4938-0`, then should consecutive calls also return "getX()"?  What (if anything) ever "changes"?  How exactly does the series "progress"?  Please show consecutive outputs, and please try to explain the "why" of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried twice put here more of my code and it was deleted...

Answer (score 0):

I have this (in class MyClass):

```
 private static int sequence = 1;
 protected String number;
 private float limitValue;
 Random rand = new Random();      
 public String x = rand.nextInt(9999)+"-"+rand.nextInt(10);    

 MyClass () { number = "0000" + sequence++; }

 public void showData() {        
     System.out.printf(" Number: %s - X: %s - Limit value: %.2f.\n", getNumber(), getX(), limitValue);            
 }
```

in my main class:

```
 MyClass y1 = new MyClass();
 value = 500f;
 y1.setLimitValue(value);        
 y1.showData();

 MyClass y2 = new MyClass();
 value = 700f;
 y2.setLimitValue(value);        
 y2.showData();

 MyClass y3 = new MyClass();
 value = 900f;
 y3.setLimitValue(value);        
 y3.showData();
```

and I got, for example, this output:

Number: 00001 - X: 3383-6 - Limit value: 500,00.
  Number: 00002 - X: 2513-4 - Limit value: 700,00.
  Number: 00003 - X: 8012-5 - Limit value: 900,00.

and my intention is get the same value of x for all y (y1, y2, y3).

Comment: If you have updates to your question, you should edit it. Don't post it as an answer. When you post an update to your question as an answer it will usually be deleted. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61240244/edit